# Manual suspension causing freezing in Ubuntu 22.04, while automatic suspension works fine. What could be the issue?

Tags: suspend, freeze

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with Ubuntu 22.04. Whenever I manually initiate the suspension process (by selecting `Suspend` from the menu or using a command), my system freezes upon waking up. However, when the system automatically suspends after a period of inactivity, I don't face any problems upon resuming.

What could be causing this discrepancy? Is there a specific setting or configuration that might be causing the manual suspension to trigger freezing? Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated.

I didn't know this issue until accidentally faced this. I already updated grub regarding my configurations in terms of graphic drivers like adding `nomodeset` or ... but none of them worked.

It seems the Ubuntu is acting differently between manual suspension and automatic.

My Laptop information:

```
Kernel: Linux 6.5.0-26-generic
Architecture: x86-64
Hardware Vendor: Lenovo
Hardware Model: IdeaPad Gaming 3 15IAH7
Graphic driver: Nvidia 545.29.06
NVML Version: 12.545.29.06
```